# Django : Why doesn't django translate the words

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

**This is my models. I have used gettext_lazy because it is models.py file**

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'),unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ("username","first_name","last_name")
```

**This is my setting.py file.I have added only**

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('fr', _('French')),
)

# Translation local path
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'locale'),
)
```

**This is done after the following process**

> python manage.py makemessages -l 'fr'

**Then a mo file is created and I add my translation there but got no translation.Then after writing the code below a po file is created and contains all the translation in pdf file**

> python manage.py compilemessages

Comment: What are you expecting translated?

Comment: @schillingt I want to translate my email_Address in models.py